# Не получается загрузить CSS в HTML

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, intellij-idea

Есть небольшое веб приложение запускаемое через idea. Проблема заключается в том, что через link совершенно не получается прогрузить стили к html странице. Стили работают только если использую style type в самой html странице. Однако, когда дело касается работы в какой-нибудь Visual Studio, то все прогружается прекрасно. По всей видимости дело в тонкостях самой idea, но в каких именно не понимаю :(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Update:**

```
<link th:href="@{/css/students_table/list.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

сработало

Comment: Посмотри в DevTools какой оно путь делает.

Comment: `/static` это зайти в корень сайта и зайти в папку static. Вам подойдёт `../../static/css/list.css` или `/main/resources/css/list.css`